# Series calculation based on shifted values / recursive algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, series

I have the following:

```
df['PositionLong'] = 0
df['PositionLong'] = np.where(df['Alpha'] == 1, 1, (np.where(np.logical_and(df['PositionLong'].shift(1) == 1, df['Bravo'] == 1), 1, 0)))
```

This lines basically only take in df['Alpha'] but not the df['PositionLong'].shift(1).. It cannot recognize it but I dont understand why?

It produces this:

```
df['Alpha']  df['Bravo']   df['PositionLong']
0               0             0
1               1             1
0               1             0
1               1             1
1               1             1
```

However what I wanted the code to do is this:

```
df['Alpha']  df['Bravo']   df['PositionLong']
0               0             0
1               1             1
0               1             1
1               1             1
1               1             1
```

I believe the solution is to loop each row, but this will take very long.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `It cannot recognize it`. It's not clear what this means. Can you give a small example showing where Python ignores the logic?

Comment: Hi jpp, I have updated with an example of the output, thank you.

Comment: So I think I see the misunderstanding. `numpy.where` does *not* work recursively. `df['PositionLong'].shift(1) == 1` will be the same as `pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 1`, i.e. all `False`, since you initiated the series as `0` previously.

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to overwrite/forwardfill based on conditions, however the other way I know how to do this is to loop through every row which will take a long time to compute. Anyway do you know how to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a **recursive function**, since a previous `PositionLong` value depends on `Alpha`, which itself is used to determine `PositionLong`.

But `numpy.where` is a regular function, so `df['PositionLong'].shift(1)` is evaluated as a series of `0` values, since you initialise the series with `0`.

A manual loop need not be expensive. You can use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) to efficiently implement your recursive algorithm:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def rec_algo(alpha, bravo):
    res = np.empty(alpha.shape)
    res[0] = 1 if alpha[0] == 1 else 0
    for i in range(1, len(res)):
        if (alpha[i] == 1) or ((res[i-1] == 1) and bravo[i] == 1):
            res[i] = 1
        else:
            res[i] = 0
    return res

df['PositionLong'] = rec_algo(df['Alpha'].values, df['Bravo'].values).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Alpha  Bravo  PositionLong
0      0      0             0
1      1      1             1
2      0      1             1
3      1      1             1
4      1      1             1
```